# Multiple flash messages in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 3.1 I can do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(Category category, @PathVariable Integer id, 
    @RequestParam("childrenOrder") int[] childrenOrder,
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if (!id.equals(category.getCategoryId())) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attempting to update the wrong category");
    categoryMapper.updateByPrimaryKey(category);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashSuccessMsg", "Update Successful");  //ADD FLASH MESSAGE
    return "redirect:/admin/categories.html";
}
```

And then show the flash message in the view:

```
 <p>${flashSuccessMsg}</p>
```

But I would rather have a list of flash messages, and then iterate over this in the view.

Is this possible?

If I do: `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("Update Successful");`
i.e. I don't name the flash message, how do I then retrive it in the view?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using [RedirectAttributes addFlashAttribute(String attributeName,
                                     Object attributeValue)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addFlashAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(Category category, @PathVariable Integer id, @RequestParam("childrenOrder") int[] childrenOrder, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (!id.equals(category.getCategoryId())) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attempting to update the wrong category");
    categoryMapper.updateByPrimaryKey(category);

    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    // populate messages 

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messages", messages);  

    return "redirect:/admin/categories.html";
}
```

Later, in your view you can iterate over `messages` using a `<c:foreach />` tag:

```
<c:foreach items="${messages}">
...
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: That is one solution, but there might be multiple methods calling addFlashAttribute.  I was hoping to avoid having to do it manually with lists.

Comment: @Mark Can you help me to know what are other ways?